# Find significance between two group proportions

Tags: proportion, sample, population

My question is the following: what statistical test would I use to compare the proportion of participants between two groups. For example, if in 2009, 20% of participants ( population was 55) to a competition were students, and in 2019, 50% of participants (population was 99) were students, how can I show that's a significant increase? I am given the sample sizes.

Comment: A proportion test. Can you edit your question by adding the sample sizes?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be looking for the Chi-squared test.

An example of this in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/chi-squared-test/

The non parametric version of this is called the Fisher exact test.

Comment: so for my contingency table, would it work if I had the two category names at the top as " student" and not "student" then my vertical categories would be "2009" then "2019." then I would have from left to right on row 1: 11 then 44 and the bottom would be 50 and 50. (I just looked at the data, and its out of 100, not 99)

Comment: Yes that should give you the correct p value